# Program doesn't work and results in an Array Out of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

My `checkTie` method in my `TicTacToe` program doesn't work and results in an out of bounds array and I can't see why.

Running this code will print the board and allow the game to run until either someone wins, or there are 3 _'s left and then it will end the game.

I'm not sure why that happens though, I believe it has something to do with my `checkTie` for loop. Also, if a tie was to occur either nothing happens or an Array out of bounds happens.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTac {

    public static int row, col;
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    public static char turn = 'X';

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = '_';
            }
        }

        Play();

    }

    public static boolean Play() {
        boolean playing = true;
        PrintBoard();
        while (playing) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Please enter row: ");
            row = scan.nextInt() - 1;
            System.out.print("Please enter column: ");
            col = scan.nextInt() - 1;
            board[row][col] = turn;
            if (GameOver(row, col)) {
                playing = false;
                System.out.println("Game Over! Player " + turn + " wins!");

               **I feel like this code below is where the problem is**

                if (checkTie(board)) {
                    System.out.println("Tie Game!");
                    return true;
                }

            }
            PrintBoard();
            if (turn == 'X')
                turn = '0';
            else
                turn = 'X';
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void PrintBoard() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (j == 0)
                    System.out.print("| ");
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean GameOver(int rMove, int cMove) {
        // Check if perpendicular victory
        if (board[0][cMove] == board[1][cMove] && board[0][cMove] == board[2][cMove])
            return true;
        if (board[rMove][0] == board[rMove][1] && board[rMove][0] == board[rMove][2])
            return true;
        // Check Diagonal Victory
        if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2] && board[1][1] != '_')
            return true;
        if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board[2][0] && board[1][1] != '_')
            return true;

        return false;

    }
```

This is where the method to see if the game result is a tie.

```
    public static boolean checkTie(char[][] board) {
        int spacesLeft = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == '_') {
                    spacesLeft++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (spacesLeft == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Tell us the *exact* input you are using to make the program crash. The code, as it stands, does not exhibit the behaviour you describe. In any case, Java will tell you the *exact* line it's failing on so you start your investiagtion there.

Comment: If you are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException you should see a detailed stack trace that will tell you in no uncertain terms exactly where it happened--no "feeling" necessary.

Comment: Oh im sorry, I fixed the OutOfBoundsException, just the game does not execute the checkTie method and does not end is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do `checkTie` when `gameOver` returns `false'.  As things stand,`checkTie`is only ever called after`gameOver' has returned `true'.